# Why Hybris controller endpoint can't be consumed as REST using tools like Postman?

Tags: spring, rest, controller, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm working with Hybris 6.2, one of the requirements is that when placing an order with a specific payment type, to hold the order creation and then through a web service endpoint to receive a request to validate the payment and then place the order.

So far, we are saving the cart once the checkout ends with this specific payment type, to handle this I saw the options to create a method on a controller on the storefront.

I created UpdateCartToOrderController with the following method (so far it should return an OK string on success):

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping(value = "/update-cart2order")
 public class UpdateCartToOrderController
 {

     private static final String OK_STATUS = "OK";

     @ResponseBody
     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String updateCartToOrder()
     {
                 // --- order creation login will be here ---
         return OK_STATUS;
     }
 }
```

When using a web browser, when I enter the path https://italika.local:9002/italikastorestorefront/italika/es/update-cart2order I see the message I'm returning with no problem, but when I tested on something like Postman I got a "Could not get any response" message.

What can I do to access this endpoint like a normal REST endpoint?

Comment: Just curious, how are you planning to call this endpoint? using AJAX call(within browser session)?

Comment: not necessarily, I wanted to expose this method to be consumed as any other REST endpoint, in my case a backend will try to consume it to perform the business logic attached to it.

Comment: since you are planning to expose MVC controller as Rest endpoint, I hope, you already think of users authentication, authorization, and session. Otherwise, Hybris webservices would be the good option.

Answer (score 0):

Try

- Using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in your URL
- Other OOTB URL (https://localhost:9002/c/YourCatagoryCode/facets)
- [using-self-signed-certificates-with-postman](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/28/using-self-signed-certificates-with-postman/)

Comment: I'm not dealing with platformwebservices yet, I wanted to expose a method in a page controller as an endpoint to be consumed by a backend.

Comment: @UrielArvizu - I don't understand your downvote, I haven't point anything to `platformwebservices` yet. Your controller seems okay, so to narrow it down I want you to test other OOTB controllers (which has @ResponseBody like `/c/23742Code/facets`) through postman and check whether it works or not. If it also not works try setting self-signed certificates. In my case, `https://localhost:9002/c/23472Code/facets` is working perfectly from the postman.

Comment: This answer should not be downvoted since the 3rd point is a good answer. The isssue might be different but with the info provided it's probably just a postman/certificate issue.

Answer (score 0):

First point is to replace you request method by post. [GET](http://%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) is to get not to modify stuff on server side. It's not related to tour issue but it's important to respect standards.

If it's working on your browser and not on Postman :

- check your browser network properties to be sure that you don't have a proxy or something that make it works
- import Chrome self-signed certificate in Postman (as mentionned in the other answer)

Comment: Based on his question/example, he is not passing anything as the parameter to update, so GET will be also fine here. But I can't understand how he planning to handed users authentication & authorization in case of exposed rest API. Anyway, he is just looking for why this URL not working with the postman.

Comment: @HybrisFreelance You do not need parameter every time to change something. The method name says "update" so I expect something to change in server side. Anyway the op issue is probably just something related to his network or to self-signed certificate.

Comment: I just want to point out that it's not breaking anything here in his example to not work with the postman. I agree, he should use POST in implementation, as POST should be used whenever there is server state change.

Comment: I left the GET method since I was just testing, eventually I would have made the method POST, but for now I just wanted try a GET, I know the method name is suggesting a server state change but this is only a test method